# Buses scheduling - every day

Tags: resource-scheduling

I have the following problem and I need some ideas to handle it:

1. I have a number of buses (approx 150) owned by individuals
   Every individual drives his own bus (or is responsible for the bus driver)
   So I don't need to care about bus drivers because buses and drivers are the same thing.
2. The above buses have to "execute/perform" bus routes on a daily base (approx 200).
3. A bus can do ONE or more routes daily
4. A bus can WORK normally 5 days a week and a certain amount of hours in a day (or month)
5. I have to find a FAIR way to distribute the daily routes every 3 months.
   Fair means that at the END of a 3 month period all the buses must have done the same number of kilometers (each bus route is assigned a fixed number of Kilometers)
6. I can't do the scheduling, at the begining, for the WHOLE 3 month period, because "special things" happen each day. Like a bus has a problem, a driver has a problem and so on.. This means that I do TODAY the NEXT DAY Schedule.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2):

[OptaPlanner](http://www.optaplanner.org/) (java, open source) has been used for such problems succesfully. Even if you don't use java, the idea's behind it could serve you well too in any language:

- 1-4: basic constraints, nothing special
- 5: [Fairness constraint](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#fairnessScoreConstraints), see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IB2CxfLhHG4)
- 6: [Continuous planning](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#continuousPlanning), see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nPagqJK3bs)